# Unable to locate the child iframe element which is within the parent iframe through Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriverwait

So far, this is what I have: I've switched the frame to its parent frame then to the the frame I am unable to locate:

```
By frame = By.xpath("//iframe[@class='GenCss_style-Model']");

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("documentflowdesk")));
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(frame));
```

Since 'frame' element is not found, I get this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element

HTML:

```
<iframe src="about:blank" name="documentflowdesk" class="gwt-Frame-NavigationComponentViewImplResourcesapplicationFrame" id="documentflowdesk" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; visibility: visible; height: 100%;"></iframe>    
#documentflowdesk
<html style="overflow: hidden;">
    <head>...</head>
    <body style="margin: 0px;" class="dragdrop-dropTarget dragdrop-boundary">
    <noscript>...</noscript>
    <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
        <div class="css-DeskStyleResources" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
            <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                <div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                    <div style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;">
                        <iframe class="GenCss_style-Model" src="/model/?modelId=100&amp;docGroupId=164&amp;connectionPointId=73" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px;"></iframe>
```

The iframe I'm trying to locate is inside multiple div. Does it have to do anything with the error? Or is there a problem with how I find my element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the HTML once you are on the *parent frame* you  have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *parent frame* to be available and switch to it.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the *child frame* to be available and switch to it.
- You can use the following solution:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='gwt-Frame-NavigationComponentViewImplResourcesapplicationFrame' and @id='documentflowdesk']")));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[@class='GenCss_style-Model' and contains(@src,'connectionPointId')]")));
  ```

Here you can find a relevant discussion on [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findelement(By.xpath(//iframe[@name='documentflowdesk']);

Thread.sleep(5000);

driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findelement(By.xpath(//ifame[@class='GenCss_style-Model']);
```