# frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt() is not helping to switch to frame

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'v AJAX based application and have some frames on it and want to switch to it hence I've used `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()` method.

Suppose now I'm on default context of a page(i.e not in any of the frames) and want to switch to `testFrame` using following code -

```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(testFrame));

   JavascriptExecutor jsExecutor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   String currentFrameName = (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("return self.name");
   System.out.println("***************** Current frame using self.name " + currentFrameName);
```

This returns empty string as a value of `currentFrameName` which indicates that we haven't switched to `testFrame`, even though explicit wait call has succeeded.

This issue reproduces intermittently which causes tests to be flaky. Could you please suggest how to make this stable?

**EDIT**

I edited my question where earlier I had mentioned - I'm in `frameA` and then want to  switch to `frameB` but that is not a case. I want to switch from default content of a page to a frame. Sorry for putting wrong information at first place.

Comment: Can you please try with --> String frame = (String) jsExecutor.executeScript("return self.location.toString()");

Comment: @Muzzamil, it returns me an url.

Comment: I think you have switched already. try this after switch --> WebElement testFrame= driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));WebElement el = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return window.frameElement");
assert testFrame.equals(el)

Answer (score 3):

You need to switch back from previous frame in order to move to another frame.using

```
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Now it should look like.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameA));
//Do somenthing.
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameB));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for putting wrong details. I corrected my question now.

Comment: @TDHM : Can you post the HTML of both frames to look how this structure.Is both frames are child of other frame or it is nested frames??

Comment: I've only one frame now, please have a look at edited question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are within *frameA* and want to switch to *frameB* will depend on the alignment of *frameA* and *frameB*.

- If *frameB* is a child frame of *frameA*, then while being in *frameA* you have to `switchTo()` the child frame *frameB* once again as follows:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameA));
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameB));
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Unable to locate the child iframe element which is within the parent iframe through Selenium in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53165931/unable-to-locate-the-child-iframe-element-which-is-within-the-parent-iframe-thro/53166628#53166628)

- If *frameA* and *frameB* both are direct child of the *Top Level Browsing Context*, then while being in *frameA* you have to `switch_to()` the [defaultContent()](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#defaultContent--) (which selects either the first frame on the page, or the main document when a page contains iframes.) first then to the frame *frameB* as follows:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameA));
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); #incase frameA and frameB are immediate child of the Top Level Content
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(frameB));
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [Multiple iframe tags Selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533101/multiple-iframe-tags-selenium-webdriver/48540002#48540002)

---

### tl; dr

You can find a relevant detailed discussion in:

- [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)

Comment: Sorry for putting wrong details. I corrected my question now.

Comment: Unfortunately your solution did not help. There is no issue with my code, it works as expected which indicates code is correct, only thing is it causes tests to fail intermittent. Hence my question is how to make it stable so it passes every time.